# CSS element class - Height differs based on content, how to fix?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Im having an issue with css.
Check my website at http://yourdesigns.nl/ssi/index.php

As you can see i have a 3-column row at the center of the index page.
Each column has a border which gives a "box-like" feeling.
The problem is that, once the content of a box is lesser then the other, the box gets smaller in height.

My goal is to give all the boxes the same height and i know this is possible by simply adding the height property to the class of my box elements, but all content is grabbed from a database, so if my client updates the content, it may be possible that the boxes are bigger then the fixed height value of the class which results in content overlapping the border/boxes.

How can i get all my boxes to be of the same height, without giving the fixed height value in my css?

Thanks in advance,

Michael

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the boxes to be able to expand to accommodate more content if needed, but you want all three to remain the same height?

Comment: Have you looked at this yet? You might find the answer here.
http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the box heights equal and prevent overflow you could set the height and overflow properties in CSS for your box class:

```
.boxes
{
   height:500px;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow:ellipsis; // ends the text block with "..." - css3 no ie7/ie8 support
}
```

If you want the boxes to re-size dynamically based on the largest box you could use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
   var largestBox = Math.max($('#box1').height(),$('#box2').height(),$('#box3').height());
   $('.boxes').height(largestBox );
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating the jQuery option: http://jsfiddle.net/EjPSw/

Comment: You're missing #box3 in your jsfiddle example.

Comment: You're welcome, we are all here to help each utter, aren't we? :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to place your boxes in a div container. The outer container should have style

```
{
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom:1px solid gray;
}
```

while the boxes inside the container should have style

```
{
    border:1px solid gray;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom: 200em;
    margin-bottom: -200em;
}
```

Follow the link for the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/eyecode/qBLpJ/1/):

Answer (score 1):

You could try using jQuery.

Give each box an id, for example box1, box2, box3;

U could use jQuery like this:

```
$(function(){
var box1 = $("#box1").height();
var box2 = $("#box2").height();
var box3 = $("#box3").height();

if((box1 > box2) && (box1 > box3))
{
   box2.height(box1);
   box3.height(box1);
} 
else if((box2 > box1) && (box2 > box3))
{
   box1.height(box2);
   box3.height(box2);
}
if((box3 > box2) && (box3 > box1))
{
   box2.height(box3);
   box1.height(box3);
}
});
```

Comment: quicker to use `Math.max` to compare box heights and select the largest, then assign it to all boxes. No if/else needed that way (see my example below)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
 min-height: 500px
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a non css3 solution, I would go for a jQuery solution by counting all the boxes and than give all boxes the highest height.